# How do I modify the legend in a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I would like to draw four circles of two colors. I'm using circle function to draw a circle. I'm facing problem with `legend()`. It colors the two data with the same color.

```
function main
clear all
clc

circle([ 10,  0], 3, 'b')
circle([-10,  0], 3, 'b')
circle([ 10, 10], 3, 'r')
circle([-10, 10], 3, 'r')

    % Nested function to draw a circle
    function circle(center,radius, color)
     axis([-20, 20, -20 20])
     hold on;
     angle = 0:0.1:2*pi;
     
     grid on

     x = center(1) + radius*cos(angle);
     y = center(2) + radius*sin(angle);
     plot(x,y, color, 'LineWidth', 2);
     xlabel('x-axis');
     ylabel('y-axis');
     title('Est vs Tr')
     legend('true','estimated');
    end


end
```

The following picture shows the problem. Both colored as blue instead one of them is red.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you draw 4 things and only  have 2 entries in the legend.
As such it will pick the color of the first four things to color the legend.

Not in the opportunity to try it myself now, but I guess that the easiest 'solution' would be to draw your third circle first and then the second one.

```
circle([ 10,  0], 3, 'b')
circle([ 10, 10], 3, 'r')
circle([-10,  0], 3, 'b')
circle([-10, 10], 3, 'r')
```

Comment: Thank you @Dennis. It solved the problem. But I have more circles so I need to keep them as a group of each color. Is there another solution for this problem? Or is there another way to draw this box without using legend, so that I can modify it as I wish?

Comment: @CroCo This is a bit too vague to answer, but perhaps you can have a look at this if you just want to set the color of the legend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957541/setting-line-colors-in-legend-of-matlab-plot

Answer (score 3):

You can make your function `circle()` return the plot handles. Store the handles in a vector. In the end, you only call `legend()` once, after plotting all circles. The first argument in legend are then the function handles which you want to appear in the legend. Something like this:

```
function main
% clear all % functions have their own workspace, this should always be empty anyway
clc
handles = NaN(1,2);
handles(1,1) = circle([ 10,  0], 3, 'b'); % handle of a blue circle
circle([-10,  0], 3, 'b')
handles(1,2) = circle([ 10, 10], 3, 'r'); % handle of a red circle
circle([-10, 10], 3, 'r')

    % Nested function to draw a circle
    function h = circle(center,radius, color) % now returns plot handle
     axis([-20, 20, -20 20])
     hold on;
     angle = 0:0.1:2*pi;
     grid on
     x = center(1) + radius*cos(angle);
     y = center(2) + radius*sin(angle);
     h = plot(x,y, color, 'LineWidth', 2);
     xlabel('x-axis');
     ylabel('y-axis');
     title('Est vs Tr')
    end

% legend outside of the function
legend(handles, 'true','estimated'); % legend for a blue and a red circle handle
end
```

The result looks like this:[image]